# Cell by cell diff in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I've seen a couple similar questions, but nothing I've found quite hits the mark with me.

I have two tables on two different sheets. The tables themselves are structured identically, but hold different content. Each data cell within the table can have MULTIPLE lines of information (e.g. E5 is 5 lines (actual lines, not wrapped) of data).

I'd like to create a third table that is also structurally identical (row 1 and column A are the same) to the first two, but have each data cell contain in some meaningful syntax the difference between the same two cells in the first two tables. It could be as straightforward as the output of a diff between the contents of the first two cells.

Is there a way to essentially take the diff of `sheet1!E5` and `sheet2!E5` and store it in `sheet3!E5` ?

EDIT:
Some clarification. All the data cells contain information on MULTIPLE lines. Some lines are present in one sheet but not in another. For instance, `sheet1!E5` may contain "string1", "string2", and "string3" on THREE lines whereas `sheet2!E5` contains "string2", "string3", "string7", and "string8" on FOUR lines. The output on `sheet3!E5` could be anything that clearly marks the difference between the two, for instance (as was mentioned before), exactly what the output would be if the two cells were text files and you ran a diff (or diff -c) on them like this:

```
*** 1,3 ****
- string1
  string2
! string3
\ No newline at end of file
--- 1,4 ----
  string2
! string3
! string7
! string8
\ No newline at end of file
```

or even just something much simpler that lists the strings that are/are not in each cell like:

```
<  string1
<> string2
<> string3
>  string7
>  string8
```

Comment: How about some sample data and expected output?

Comment: If these are substrings that you are looking for a way to "take the diff", then put this formula for E5 cell in Sheet3: `=REPLACE(Sheet2!E5,FIND(Sheet1!E5,Sheet2!E5,1),LEN(Sheet1!E5‌​),"")`

Comment: @Tehscript, that kinda seems to work situationally. For instance, for cells where there's only one line in sheet2 and sheet1 is blank, it'll correctly tell me that that line is missing. It also looks like if sheet1 contains consecutive rows that exist in sheet2 and one of those rows is either the first or last row in sheet2, it DOES correctly list the missing rows (the rows missing from the beginning or end), but adds a blank line to the first row of the output, which excel's autosizing rows does NOT like at all, making the cell look blank at first.

Comment: @Tehscript other scenarios, for instance, sheet1 containing a rows in the middle of sheet2 (unlike before where it had to be a continuous range that includes either the first or last row), result in #VALUE! errors.

Comment: @Tehscript looked around a bit more learned some more. It has nothing to do with the blank rows. Apparently excel just can't autosize rows based on cells that have multiple rows pulled via formulas (but can if the rows were manually typed in). I'm looking into some VBA to fix that so no worries there, though ideally the solution should NOT pick up the actual newline character between rows when listing differences. Due to this behavior, I did find that some of the cells that I thought were single line results were actually multiple lines. I'll have to compare further to see if these are correct

Comment: This will be pretty complex to do with native Excel, given the constraints you've mentioned so far.  I suggest you write a vba macro to accomplish your goals.  If you cannot get that to work, edit your question to include the code, error messages, and more detail on **exactly** how and where you want the output, as well as its format.  If you want to mimic the Unix `diff` command, you will most definitely need to write a VBA macro

Comment: ok, fully tested @Tehscript's thing. It works as long as sheet1's rows are a contiguous range of sheet2's rows. but if sheet1 contains for instance, the first and last of sheet2's rows, that's what returns the error.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'm aware this probably requires VBA, which is why it was tagged as such. you can assume the output can match a "diff -c" of the two sets of data exactly, as was mentioned in the edit I made. I think I was pretty clear on the "where I want the output" part (the cell in sheet3 respective to the two cells in sheet1 and sheet2 that are being diff'd).

I am not very experienced with VBA and do not know where to start, which is why I asked this question.

Comment: OK.  I suggest you start with an internet search on *learning VBA*.  You should also be as precise as you can about exactly what you want. The Unix `diff` command is pretty sophisticated, and you may not really need all the bells and whistles. This forum is not a free code-writing service but we can help with code you are trying to develop. I think if I **had to** duplicate `diff` functionality, I'd work out a way to process my data using Unix (or Linux).  But there may be other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem I made the following VBA code.  It isn't verbatim because VBA doesn't allow short circuit operators and I needed PrintDiff to return the string instead of displaying it.

```
Function LCSLength(C() As Integer, X() As String, Y() As String, M As Integer, N As Integer) As Integer

    Dim I As Integer
    For I = 0 To M
        C(I, LBound(Y)) = 0
    Next

    Dim J As Integer
    For J = 0 To N
        C(LBound(X), J) = 0
    Next

    For I = 1 To M
        For J = 1 To N
            If X(I) = Y(J) Then
                C(I, J) = C(I - 1, J - 1) + 1
            ElseIf C(I, J - 1) < C(I - 1, J) Then
                C(I, J) = C(I - 1, J)
            Else
                C(I, J) = C(I, J - 1)
            End If
        Next
    Next

    LCSLength = C(M, N)

End Function

Function PrintDiff(C() As Integer, X() As String, Y() As String, I As Integer, J As Integer) As String

    Continue = 1

    If Continue = 1 And I > 0 And J > 0 Then
        If X(I) = Y(J) Then
            PrintDiff = PrintDiff(C, X, Y, I - 1, J - 1) & Chr(10) & "<> " & X(I)
            Continue = 0
        End If
    End If

    If Continue = 1 And J > 0 Then
        If I = 0 Then
            PrintDiff = PrintDiff(C, X, Y, I, J - 1) & Chr(10) & ">   " & Y(J)
            Continue = 0
        ElseIf C(I, J - 1) >= C(I - 1, J) Then
            PrintDiff = PrintDiff(C, X, Y, I, J - 1) & Chr(10) & ">   " & Y(J)
            Continue = 0
        End If
    End If

    If Continue = 1 And I > 0 Then
        If J = 0 Then
            PrintDiff = PrintDiff(C, X, Y, I - 1, J) & Chr(10) & "<   " & X(I)
            Continue = 0
        ElseIf C(I, J - 1) < C(I - 1, J) Then
            PrintDiff = PrintDiff(C, X, Y, I - 1, J) & Chr(10) & "<   " & X(I)
            Continue = 0
        End If
    End If

    If Continue = 1 Then
        PrintDiff = ""
    End If

End Function

Function Diff(A As String, B As String) As String

    Dim X() As String
    X = Split(Chr(10) & A, Chr(10))

    Dim M As Integer
    If (A = "") Then
        M = 0
    Else
        M = UBound(X)
    End If

    Dim Y() As String
    Y = Split(Chr(10) & B, Chr(10))

    Dim N As Integer
    If (B = "") Then
        N = 0
    Else
        N = UBound(Y)
    End If

    Dim C() As Integer
    ReDim C(M, N) As Integer

    Call LCSLength(C, X, Y, M, N)
    Diff = Mid(PrintDiff(C, X, Y, M, N), 2)

End Function
```

If A1 contains:

```
string1
string2
string3
```

And B1 contains:

```
string2
string3
string7
string8
```

And if C1 contains `=Diff(A1,B1)` then C1 will display:

```
<  string1
<> string2
<> string3
>  string7
>  string8
```

According to the "Code optimization" section on that page several optimizations can be made to the code - I haven't done those in this code.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help here. This seems to do exactly what I need, but there's one thing that could change. Right now, it reads empty cells as some sort of null value that it treats the same way as a blank row (which I guess makes sense in a way). The problem is how it behaves with other formulas I have designed to count the number of lines in each cell. Ideally, each cell in the 3rd table should have a number of lines equal to the number of unique lines between the first and second sheets, but this doesn't happen because every diff("","") returns a "<>" ...

Comment: and every dif("","1") returns a "<" line and a ">  1" line. One workaround I found was to add a blank line to the beginning of every cell with data in it and subtract 1 from every cell's line count in the 3rd table, but that quickly becomes tedious. Is there a quick patch here that would make it ignore blank cells (but still properly spit out a difference)? Phrased another way, how can I ever get a diff output that just reads (for example) "> 1" with no other lines?

Comment: @creepblockedunderturret I have fixed it so it returns a size of 0 when the string is empty - I think it does what you want now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. duplicate your structure in Sheet 3, and simply make sure all your references are accurate. For example, in cell A1 on sheet 3, you would just type:

```
= [navigate to sheet1!A1 and click it] - [navigate to sheet2!A1 and click it]
```

pretty easy, actually.

Comment: you can't just subtract two cells with multiple lines of data to get a comparison of the two sets of data . . .

Comment: ah, I misread. sorry about that. FTR, this seems like extremely poor spreadsheet design

Comment: I know it's not the most common format, but it does make sense for what I'm tracking.